# Windows: How to use "set" with dynamic search and replace?

Tags: windows, batch-file, environment-variables

I want to use the search/replace feature of the `SET` command in a dynamic fashion.

The normal way would be like

```
SET blah=double-foo
SET blah=%blah:foo=bar%
```

Now I want to use variables in the second line instead of `foo` and `bar`:

```
SET search=foo
SET repl=bar
SET blah=double-foo

ECHO %blah%
SET blah=%blah:%search%=%repl%%
ECHO %blah%
```

I only get

```
double-foo
searchrepl%
```

I also tried

```
SET blah=%blah:(%search%=%repl%)%
SET blah=%blah:(%search%)=(%repl%)%
```

How would I achieve this? If I do this without `SET` that's fine. In the end I want the environment variable to hold `double-bar`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two common ways (and some uncommon).

Use the double expansion by call.

```
SET search=foo
SET repl=bar
SET blah=double-foo

CALL SET blah=%%blah:%search%=%repl%%%
```

In the first "scan" it expands to `CALL SET blah=%blah:foo=bar%` and the call expands the seconds time to the desired result.

The second way is the delayed variant

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET search=foo
SET repl=bar
SET blah=double-foo

SET blah=!blah:%search%=%repl%!
```

It works, because delayed expansion executes after the percent expansion.

I would prefer the delayed variant, because it's faster and safer against special characters.

An uncommon way is the FOR-Loop-Variable variant, it works also with special characters in the search/replace variables.

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET "search=foo>"
SET "repl=bar & bar"
SET "blah=double-foo> &|<>"

for %%s in ("!search!") do (
  for %%r in ("!repl!") do (
    SET "blah=!blah:%%~s=%%~r!"
  )
)
```

Comment: Delayed expansion is also documented while the `call` one is not :-)

Comment: @Joey: Yes, it is undocumented, but the effects of `call` are well known (double expansion, doubling the carets and disabling delayed expansion)

Comment: +1 awesome! For those who care: it also works with the batch parameters `CALL SET blah=%%blah:%1=%2%%`